# Ruby: array of hashes - how to remove duplicates based on the hash key which is an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes in which the key of each hash is and array containing 2 integers - look like this:

```
  [{[6, 8]=>0.5932190854209105}, {[6, 13]=>0.7183325285691291}, {[6, 15]=>0.8253727388780498}, {[8, 6]=>0.5932190854209105}, {[8, 13]=>0.7255537819950661}, {[8, 15]=>0.5249232568337963}, {[13, 6]=>0.7183325285691291}, {[13, 8]=>0.7255537819950661}, {[13, 15]=>0.6348636166265346}, {[15, 6]=>0.8253727388780497}, {[15, 8]=>0.5249232568337963}, {[15, 13]=>0.6348636166265343}]
```

I need to remove duplicates - in this case a duplicate is defined as a hash whose key already exist (but in reverse order). So for example [6, 15] and [15,6]. You can see that based on this definition half of these are duplicates.

Just to add to this:

This is formed from the following

```
 @user_array.each do |u|
   @result << @user_array.map { |p| Hash[[u, p] => kappa(u, p, "ipf")] if p !=u  }
 end
```

user_array is an array of integers (user ids). For example :

```
  [6, 8, 13, 15]
```

I need to run the kappa helper on each unorder paired combination. I can seem to work out how to prevent it "doubling up". I figured if I could save the pair somehow then I could make comparisons. The only way I knew how to do that is by using a hash. I am fairly new.

EDIT: I tried sort like this:

```
@user_array.each do |u|
   @result << @user_array.map { |p| Hash[[u, p].sort => kappa(u, p, "ipf")] if p !=u  }
end
```

But they are discrete hashes...so it doesn't work:

```
 [{[6, 8]=>0.5932190854209105}, {[6, 13]=>0.7183325285691291}, {[6, 15]=>0.8253727388780498}, {[6, 8]=>0.5932190854209105}, {[8, 13]=>0.7255537819950661}, {[8, 15]=>0.5249232568337963}, {[6, 13]=>0.7183325285691291}, {[8, 13]=>0.7255537819950661}, {[13, 15]=>0.6348636166265346}, {[6, 15]=>0.8253727388780497}, {[8, 15]=>0.5249232568337963}, {[13, 15]=>0.6348636166265343}]
```

Its not that straightforward.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your definition of "duplicate".  The keys are pair contained in the array; otherwise, the hash functionality would be able to "take care of" their entries without you needing to intervene.  How are you inserting the keys?

Comment: I think I know what your are saying....but they are discrete hashes with know knowledge of each other

Comment: can you show more examples ?

Comment: That solution is extremely messy and creates a staggering amount of garbage.

Comment: OK. For my knowledge, could you explain that last comment.

Comment: Why the mad rush to select an answer? Other answers are on their way you know. Questions are questions. Answers are answers. Please don't incorporate answers in questions. Not that you can always answer your own question (if your answer is different than the others already posted).

Comment: Fixed. The solution that was given worked very well.

Comment: Not only do quick-draw answers short-circuit those still working on their answers, but it may discourage some from posting what might be better (or just interesting) answers. Is there some reason not to wait a reasonable amount of time, at least, say, a couple of hours? There's no rush, you know.

Comment: Fair enough. Point taken.

Comment: If you've added a hash with key `[1,2]`, is another hash with the same key to be retained or excluded, or must the second hash have key `[2,1]` for it to be excluded? Do you want to mutate the array of hashes or return a different array and leave the original unchanged?

Comment: Either should be excluded.

Comment: When you give an example, it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = [{[6, 8]=>0.59...]`). That way, readers can refer to the variable(s) (`arr`) in answers and comments without having to define it (them), and all readers will use the same variable(s). Generally there's no need to do that for desired or expected output objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as your `kappa` function produces the same value for `u,p` as for `p,u` then you can do this:

```
@result = @user_array.each_with_object({ }) do |u, h|
  @user_array.each do |p|
    next if (u == p)

    h[[u, p].sort] ||= kappa(u, p, "ipf")
  end
end
```

That populates the values once and once only. If you want to do it where the last value sticks then change `||=` to `=`.

Comment: One minor addition

Comment: I had to add - unless u==p in line 3 but otherwise this is terrific. I would like to know why my answer was crap - I am sure its is, but would like a bit of knowledge if possible

Comment: "Crap" is a harsh assessment for code that actually works. "Sub-optimal" is how I'd put it. Creating N hashes and then merging them together, each operation of which creates *another* intermediate hash, is extremely wasteful, each of these needs to be dealt with by the garbage collector. It's much neater to create one hash and insert everything into that.

Comment: Added the `next` statement to skip over the insertion if the values are identical. I didn't see your `if` in the original since you have to scroll to see it. That's why I advocate not using trailing `if` or `unless` clauses except when dealing with things like `next` or `break` or `return`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you could head this off at the pass if you sorted the arrays.  Since you're stating that any permutation of the pairs is equivalent, then a sort before insertion would allow the hash to eliminate/overwrite any duplicate values.

```
@user_array.each do |u|
   @result << @user_array.map { |p| Hash[[u, p].sort => kappa(u, p, "ipf")] if p !=u  }
 end
```

Comment: If you keep the keys sorted it's impossible to have duplicates.

Comment: Look at the array, it's not a hash, it's an array of individual hashes.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment the OP has clarified that if an element (hash) of the array is to be retained, and the (only) key of that hash is `[a,b]`, no subsequent hash with key `[a,b]` or `[b,a]` is to be retained.

Let `arr` denote your array of hashes, each having a single key/value pair.

You can use [Enumerable#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) or [Enumerable#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21), depending on whether `arr` is to be modified in place.

```
arr.uniq { |h| h.first.first.sort }
  #=> [{[6, 8]=>0.5932190854209105}, {[6, 13]=>0.7183325285691291},
  #    {[6, 15]=>0.8253727388780498}, {[8, 13]=>0.7255537819950661},
  #    {[8, 15]=>0.5249232568337963}, {[13, 15]=>0.6348636166265346}]
```

or, to modify `arr` in place,

```
arr.uniq! { |h| h.first.first.sort } || arr
  #=> [{[6, 8]=>0.5932190854209105}, {[6, 13]=>0.7183325285691291},
  #    {[6, 15]=>0.8253727388780498}, {[8, 13]=>0.7255537819950661},
  #    {[8, 15]=>0.5249232568337963}, {[13, 15]=>0.6348636166265346}] 
arr
  #=> [{[6, 8]=>0.5932190854209105}, {[6, 13]=>0.7183325285691291},
  #    {[6, 15]=>0.8253727388780498}, {[8, 13]=>0.7255537819950661},
  #    {[8, 15]=>0.5249232568337963}, {[13, 15]=>0.6348636166265346}]
```

`|| arr` is needed in case `arr` contains no duplicates, in which case `uniq!` returns `nil`.

You could alternatively write

```
require 'set'
arr.uniq { |h| h.first.first.to_set }
```

(or `uniq!`).

To quote from `uniq`'s doc, "`self` is traversed in order, and the first occurrence is kept."